# Python 3.x - How to get the directory where user installed package

Tags: python, installation, package

Suppose that I am building a Python package with the following folder tree:

```
main
|-- setup.py
|-- the_package
     |--globar_vars.py
     |--the_main_script.py
```

When the user performs anyway to install it, like:

```
sudo python setup.py install
python setup.py install --user
python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local
```

Or well, using PIP:

```
pip install 'SomeProject'
```

I want that the folder where the package was installed be saved on the `global_vars.py`, in any variable, Eg:

```
globarl_vars.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

user_installed_pkg = '/some/path/where/the/package/was/installed'
```

There is someway to get it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `SomeProject` package is a [well-formed Python package](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/) (which can be done using [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html)), a user can derive the location simply use the [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) module provided by `setuptools` package to get this information.  For example:

```
>>> from pkg_resources import working_set
>>> from pkg_resources import Requirement
>>> working_set.find(Requirement.parse('requests'))
requests 2.2.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages)
>>> working_set.find(Requirement.parse('requests')).location
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
```

However, the path returned could be something inside an egg which means it will not be a path directly usable through standard filesystem tools.  You generally want to use the [Resource manager API](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api) to access resources in those cases.

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> api_src = pkg_resources.resource_string('requests', 'api.py')
>>> api_src[:25]
b'# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\n\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import wtv_module
print(wtv_module.__file__)

import os
print(os.path.dirname(wtv_module.__file__))
```

Comment: I was considering this option. However, this way only work when the package is already installed. I mean, your answer just solve the half of the problem. I get the path where the package was installed (great), now it remain to assign that path to the variable into the global_var.py file (which is also already installed).

Comment: Ok, may be splitting the work could be the solution ;)